# Should only 1 view go in 1 Activity, in Android?

Tags: android

What is "best practice"? 
Should each view have its own Activity? Never 2 views in 1 Activity?

Comment: An activity can contain hundreds of `View`s. For example, each row item in a `ListActivity` is a `View`

Answer (score 1):

No no no... each *widget* is a View. Each Activity should have a Layout and each Layout should have multiple Views.

So, imagine you have this layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="View 1" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="View 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Both of those `TextView`s are Views. The `LinearLayout` is a `ViewGroup` and the whole thing makes up a Layout. An `Activity` would bind to the Layout then you could get handles to any of the Views.

If you're asking whether each `Activity` should have it's own layout then the answer is, generally speaking, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use tab widget. Please reference this "Hello, TabWidget". (http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)